# awk compare two files and merge output

Tags: awk

### Original question

I have 2 files `1.csv` and `2.csv`

1.csv:-

```
AK,BA,Alpha,1095  
ALL,SA,Alpha,9592
```

2.csv:-

```
AK,BA,SPAM,10
```

I want to merge files so that it will print output file as below

OUTPUT:-

```
AK,BA,Alpha,1095,SPAM,10  
AL,SA,Alpha,9592,NA,NA
```

---

### Updated question

I have 2 files `alpha1.csv` and `SPAM1.csv`

```
$ cat alpha1.csv  
AKTEL_BANGLADESH,BANGLADESH,Alphanumeric_A_MSISDN_blocking,1095  
ALJAWAL_SAUDI_TELECOM_COMPANY,SAUDI_ARABIA,Alphanumeric_A_MSISDN_blocking,9592  
B-MOBILE_BRUNEI,BRUNEI,Alphanumeric_A_MSISDN_blocking,3  


$ cat SPAM1.csv  
AIN_AIS_GLOBAL_COMMUNICATIONS,THAILAND,SPAM_CHAIN_SMS_REJECT(Spam_Detection_and_Blocking),1  
AKTEL_BANGLADESH,BANGLADESH,SPAM_CHAIN_SMS_REJECT(Spam_Detection_and_Blocking),16  
ALJAWAL_SAUDI_TELECOM_COMPANY,SAUDI_ARABIA,SPAM_CHAIN_SMS_REJECT(Spam_Detection_and_Blocking),10593  
AT&T_WIRELESS,UNITED_STATES,SPAM_CHAIN_SMS_REJECT(Spam_Detection_and_Blocking),218  
BANGLALINK_SHEBA_BANGLADESH,BANGLADESH,SPAM_CHAIN_SMS_REJECT(Spam_Detection_and_Blocking),111
```

expected output:

```
AIN_AIS_GLOBAL_COMMUNICATIONS,THAILAND,SPAM_CHAIN_SMS_REJECT(Spam_Detection_and_Blocking),1,**NA,NA**  
AKTEL_BANGLADESH,BANGLADESH,SPAM_CHAIN_SMS_REJECT(Spam_Detection_and_Blocking),16,Alphanumeric_A_MSISDN_blocking,1095  
ALJAWAL_SAUDI_TELECOM_COMPANY,SAUDI_ARABIA,SPAM_CHAIN_SMS_REJECT(Spam_Detection_and_Blocking),10593,Alphanumeric_A_MSISDN_blocking,9592  
AT&T_WIRELESS,UNITED_STATES,SPAM_CHAIN_SMS_REJECT(Spam_Detection_and_Blocking),218,**NA,NA**  
BANGLALINK_SHEBA_BANGLADESH,BANGLADESH,SPAM_CHAIN_SMS_REJECT(Spam_Detection_and_Blocking),111,**NA,NA**  
B-MOBILE_BRUNEI,BRUNEI,**NA,NA**,Alphanumeric_A_MSISDN_blocking,3
```

My command is only printing matched cases of file two with file 1 and not printing non matched cases:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} FNR==NR {a[$1,$2]=$3 FS $4; next} {print $0, (i=a[$1,$2]?a[$1,$2]:"NA,NA")}' alpha1.csv SPAM1.csv  
AIN_AIS_GLOBAL_COMMUNICATIONS,THAILAND,SPAM_CHAIN_SMS_REJECT(Spam_Detection_and_Blocking),1,NA,NA  
AKTEL_BANGLADESH,BANGLADESH,SPAM_CHAIN_SMS_REJECT(Spam_Detection_and_Blocking),16,Alphanumeric_A_MSISDN_blocking,1095  
ALJAWAL_SAUDI_TELECOM_COMPANY,SAUDI_ARABIA,SPAM_CHAIN_SMS_REJECT(Spam_Detection_and_Blocking),10593,Alphanumeric_A_MSISDN_blocking,9592  
AT&T_WIRELESS,UNITED_STATES,SPAM_CHAIN_SMS_REJECT(Spam_Detection_and_Blocking),218,NA,NA  
BANGLALINK_SHEBA_BANGLADESH,BANGLADESH,SPAM_CHAIN_SMS_REJECT(Spam_Detection_and_Blocking),111,NA,NA
```

Comment: Isn't this duplicate of your previous question?

Comment: Yes but much simplified, i am deleting previous one.

Comment: Ah... Then the idea is to compare files by 1st and 2nd fields, right?

Comment: yes, but point is no details should be ignored, if not matched with second file then should print na OR 0 at that place.

Comment: my command is only printing matched cases
$ awk -F, 'BEGIN {OFS=",";} NR == FNR {a[$1,$2] = $0;} NR != FNR {print $0, a[$1,$2] ,$3;}' 1.csv 2.csv| cut -d, -f1,2,3,4,7,8

Output: AK,BA,SPAM,10,Alpha,1095

Comment: I see. Check my answer, where I handle the case when the array field is not present.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this, for example:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} FNR==NR {a[$1,$2]=$3 FS $4; next} {print $0, (($1,$2) in a?a[$1,$2]:"NA,NA")}' f2 f1
AK,BA,Alpha,1095,SPAM,10
ALL,SA,Alpha,9592,NA,NA
```

#### Explanation

- `BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}` set input and output field separator as comma.
- `FNR==NR {a[$1,$2]=$3 FS $4; next}` store 3rd and 4th values in an array `a[]`, whose index is the tuple `($1,$2)`.
- `{print $0, (($1,$2) in a?a[$1,$2]:"NA,NA")}` print the line together with the matched item from the array. If there is no such element, then print `NA,NA`.

Comment: What's the purpose of the `i=`? Also, `a[$1,$2]` as the condition in the ternary expression will evaluate to false if the array contains a value that evaluates to 0 - you should really be testing for `($1,$2) in a`.

Comment: Pretty true... I somehow thought assigning to a variable was needed. Then, would `{print $0, (($1,$2) in a?a[$1,$2]:"NA,NA")}` be correct? It is working fine, but I don't know if there is any other unaccuracy.

Comment: Yes, that's the way to do it.

Comment: Fedorui,
I guess its still not working. See in question if i change sequence of both the files then no. of lines in output are different. So in both the condition its ignoring some data.

Comment: @user2761031 what do you mean? The code I wrote is based on your sample input and expected output. To clarify, update your question with more info. But if it is a new requirement, you'd better [Ask a new Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: its the same requirement, i just do not understand why its ignoring data. Is there any way i can attach my input files here ?

Comment: So if i use below command then, if line of SPAM.csv not matched with alpha.csv for alpha it is writing NA,NA but if line of alpha not matched with SPAM then completely ignoring data of that line of alpha and not printing.  
in short its matching SPAM.csv with alpha but not alpha.csv with SPAM. I expected a combined output. so if some details of alpha are not matched with span so for spam also it should ryt NA,NA but here its only writing for alpha.

Comment: Note you have to provide sample data representative enough to make it understandable. With the input you have, the idea was to get items from the first file and print together with the second. Update your question with some representative sample data and indicate what it is the expected output.

Comment: I have updated question. I hope its clear now. pls help

Comment: any clue how to do it ?

Comment: Or want me to post a seperate question ?

Comment: @user2761031 I have been checking this an the approach has to be different. My current answer gets the strings from `alpha` and then tries to match them in `spam`. What you want now is to match everything with everything, which needs another way of handling it, that I cannot figure out right now. So yes, I suggest you to post a new question so that more people can think of an approach.